# DevExpress GridView VisibleRowCount

Tags: gridview, devexpress

I'm having difficulty with obtaining VisibleRowCount in my gridview.  I have this particular gridview which I populate via
    NewButton/>
, inserting a new row, then populating each column, then attempting to do a save.

However whenever I do a save,

```
grdView.VisibleRowCount
```

always returns zero.  Even though the grid is populated, with clearly visible data.

Note: this gridview contains  KeyFieldName="xxx", which I do not populate, when inserting a new row, via the Newbutton/>.  I intend to populate this value in my save routine once I am able to access the data in the gridView.  Might the fact be that this key field not being populated in the gridview be the problem?  Is there a way to default that value via the NewButton/>  function?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I know this is a little dated but did you ever find a solution? We've been using the Gridview for years and after we updated our working source from v19.x to v20.x we are now seeing VisbibleRowCount = 0 when rows are present. If we revert back to v19 it works again. Something changed since v19x

Answer (score 0):

Refer: [AspxGridView - VisibleRowCount always 0](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q563615/aspxgridview-visiblerowcount-always-0)

> Please note that the ASPxGridView control does not store data between
>   server requests. Therefore, it is required to bind Grid on every
>   request to the server. Refer to the [Why might paging (sorting,
>   grouping, filtering) not work in the ASPxGridView](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/K18183.aspx)? KB article for
>   additional details.
>
> At the same time, visible GridView rows may be cached when the
>   [ASPxGridView.EnableRowsCache Propert](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxGridViewASPxGridView_EnableRowsCachetopic)y is set to True. Check if
>   this property is True in your project. See the [ASPxGridView Row
>   Cache](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/K18567.aspx) KB article for additional details.

There are lots of DevExpress thread explaining this behavior. Please check these:
[DevExpress QA link](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=aspxgridview%20visiblerowcount%200&oq=aspxgridview%20vis&aqs=chrome.5.69i57j0l5.15611j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)